# Calling SNS when AWS Step Function fails

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-step-functions

I have implemented a state machine using AWS Step Functions which includes calling some Lambda functions, Spinning EMR cluster, Adding steps to EMR and Terminating EMR cluster. I want to call SNS Topic whenever any of above state fails.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a cloudwatch event to capture the stepfunction failure or time out events and add SNS as the target for this rule.

to create a cloudwatch rule navigate to cloudwatch -> events -> rules -> create

this rule can be restricted to a specific stepfunction or a specific execution providing the corresponding ARN

[image]

Comment: Thanks but I don't want an event when Step Function fails. I actually want to receive events when any of the state of step function fails.

Comment: you can add similar cloudwatch events for the lambdas in the stepfunction

Comment: Hi, actually I want to get notified if any of state of step function fails.. Like if 2 states fails, SNS will send mail to my email that this state has failed.